# Inheritance has no attribute?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x

```
class Airplane:

    def __init__(self, plane_model, serial_num, num_seats, miles_travelled):
        self.model = plane_model
        self.serial = serial_num
        self.seat = num_seats
        self.miles = miles_travelled

class Flight:

    def __init__(self, plane):
        self.passangers = []
        self.airplane = plane
```

I am trying to complete the following function:

```
    def add(self, passenger):
        """(Flight, str) -> bool

        If there are still seats avalaible on this flight, add passenger to the passenger list.       
        Return true iff passenger is added to this flight.

        >>> a = Airplane('Cesna 150E', '9378', 1, 824.8)
        >>> f = Flight(a)
        >>> f.add('Myrto') # Decreases the seat by 1
        True
        >>> f.add('Jen') # No more seats avalaible
        False
        """
```

So far, my attempt:

```
        if self.seat > 0:
            self.seat -= 1 #num_seats
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Of course, naturally, the instance variable `num_seats` would decrease by one if a passenger is added. The number of seats available is indicated on the third parameter on the `Airplane` class.

If I use the function that I have designed, attempting the exact same action like the one in the docstring returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    f.add('a')
  File "/Users/N/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 39, in add
    if self.seat > 0:
AttributeError: 'Flight' object has no attribute 'seat'
```

I think I may be missing something but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Did you mean `self.plane.seat`?

Comment: Also, your title mentions *"inheritance"* but *you don't actually have any*. If `Flight` should inherit from `Airplane` (I don't think it should; composition rather than inheritance is the right choice here) it should be `class Flight(Airplane):`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it should be a composition rather than inheritance. My apologies. I solved it using self.airplane.seat instead though. Perhaps it needs me to refer to a class that has the self.seat attribute in it.

Comment: I mean you already have composition, it's only the title that's wrong. By accessing `self.airplane.seat` you *are* referring to a class that has the `self.seat`.

Comment: Well, no, that's referring to an OBJECT who has the `seat` attribute.

Comment: @LennartRegebro good point well made; it's an *instance* of the *class* that has a `seat` instance *attribute*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific error is that a `Flight` instance doesn't have a `seat` attribute, that's an attribute of an `Airplane` instance and should therefore be accessed via the `self.airplane` attribute (which provides the link to the `Airplane` instance that will be used for the `Flight` instance):

```
if self.airplane.seat > 0:
      # ^ access via 'airplane' attribute
```

However, I think your modelling is slightly off generally. The addition of passengers changes the *number of free seats on the `Flight` instance*, but does not alter the *number of seats on the `Airplane` instance* (as far as I'm aware, they don't start stripping seats out of the plane as people book!) Also, the distance to be travelled is a property of the flight, not the aeroplane. With that in mind, I would implement as:

```
class Airplane(object):

    def __init__(self, model, seats):
        self.model = model
        self.seats = seats


class Flight(object):

    def __init__(self, plane, code, distance):
        self.plane = plane
        self.code = code
        self.distance = distance
        self.passengers = []

    @property
    def free_seats(self):
        return self.plane.seats - len(self.passengers)

    def add(self, passenger):
        if not self.free_seats:
            raise Exception("Flight full.")
        self.passengers.append(passenger)
```

Note that `Flight.add` checks to ensure that the current `passengers` list will fit into the `plane.seats`. There is no need to keep a separate attribute - `free_seats` can be calculated from other attributes, so I've made it a read-only `property`. In use:

```
>>> f = Flight(Airplane("747", 5), "BA0123", 123)
>>> for person in ['John Cleese', 'Terry Gilliam', 'Eric Idle', 'Terry Jones', 'Michael Palin']:
    f.add(person)


>>> f.passengers
['John Cleese', 'Terry Gilliam', 'Eric Idle', 'Terry Jones', 'Michael Palin']
>>> f.add('Graham Chapman')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    f.add('Graham Chapman')
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 13, in add
    raise Exception("Flight full.")
Exception: Flight full.
>>> f.free_seats
0
```

*(Don't worry, Graham's past caring at this point.)*

This does not quite meet your specification, as `Flight.add` now raises an error if the flight is full, rather than returning `False`. This is a more Pythonic way of coding; see [*"Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp).